# How to add row delete confirmation message on handsontable

Tags: javascript, handsontable

In handsontable row_remove contextmenu, is it possible to attach the confirmation message before deleting row so that user has option to cancel request?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. In the documentation there is a [beforeRemoveRow](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.17.0/Hooks.html#event:beforeRemoveRow) that can be used to call a function before the row is removed.

You can use it in the delcaration of the table:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var container = document.getElementById('basic_example');

  var data = function () {
   return Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(100, 12);
  };

  var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: data(),
    height: 396,
    colHeaders: true,
    rowHeaders: true,
    stretchH: 'all',
    columnSorting: true,
    contextMenu: true,
    beforeRemoveRow: function(){return confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this row?")}
  });

});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2b6kL2dg/) with the example.